# JQuery Dialog w/ .NET: Hidden Div shows after unrelated postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, postback, dialog

I'm using a very simple JQuery dialog box.  User clicks on a link, and the previously hidden dialog box opens.  It works great with one catch:  There are unrelated buttons on the same page which cause a post-back.  If one of these buttons are clicked, the hidden div for the dialog box shows up on the screen, but without the style.

Stripped down to the essentials for this post, here's what I've got:

```
<a href="#" id="Choose_a_Customer-link"><img alt="Reliabills" src="/billingsystem/images/icn_help.png" border="0" /></a>

<div id="Choose_a_Customer" title="Choose a Customer Help"><p>Coming Soon...!</p></div>

<script>
$(function() {$("#Choose_a_Customer").dialog({ autoOpen: false, buttons: [{ text: "Ok", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }], width: 400 });

$("#Choose_a_Customer-link").click(function(event) { $("#Choose_a_Customer").dialog("open"); event.preventDefault(); });});

</script>

<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cnt$cmd_clients" value="Go >" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cnt$cmd_clients&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;client&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_cnt_cmd_clients" />
```

That last button is the .NET button which in the .aspx page looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmd_clients" runat="server" Text="Go >" ValidationGroup="client" />
```

And it's the button causing the problems. When it is clicked, I see "Coming Soon...!" without the dialog box around it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set display:none for div by default:

```
<div style="display:none" id="Choose_a_Customer" title="Choose a Customer Help"><p>Coming Soon...!</p></div>
```

and

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pageLoad() {
    $("#Choose_a_Customer").dialog({ autoOpen: false, buttons: [{ text: "Ok", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }], width: 400 });
  }
</script>
```

this code works:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">       
            <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <a href="#" id="Choose_a_Customer-link">Show dialog</a>
                    <div id="Choose_a_Customer" title="Choose a Customer Help">
                        <p>Coming Soon...!</p>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        function pageLoad() {
                            $("#Choose_a_Customer").dialog({ autoOpen: false, buttons: [{ text: "Ok", click: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }], width: 400 });
                            $("#Choose_a_Customer-link").click(function(event) { $("#Choose_a_Customer").dialog("open"); event.preventDefault(); });
                        };
                    </script>
                    <!--<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cnt$cmd_clients" value="Go >" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$cnt$cmd_clients&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;client&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_cnt_cmd_clients" />-->
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go >" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

For multiply instances:
file **WebUserControl1.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebUserControl1" %>
<a href="#" id="Choose_a_Customer-link<%=ID %>"><%=LinkText %></a>
<div id="Choose_a_Customer<%=ID %>" title="Choose a Customer Help">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" />    
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go >" OnClick="Button1_Click"  />
```

file **WebUserControl1.ascx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public class htmlContainer : Control, INamingContainer
        {
        }

        private ITemplate contentTemplate = null;

        [TemplateContainer(typeof(htmlContainer))]
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        public ITemplate ContentTemplate
        {
            get{ return contentTemplate; }
            set{ contentTemplate = value; }
        }

        void Page_Init()
        {
            if (contentTemplate != null)
            {
                htmlContainer container = new htmlContainer();
                contentTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);
            }
        }

        public string LinkText { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "key" + ID, 
String.Format(@"
$(document).ready(function(){{
    $(""#Choose_a_Customer{0}"").dialog({{ autoOpen: false, buttons: [{{ text: ""Ok"", click: function () {{ $(this).dialog(""close""); }} }}], width: 400 }});
    $(""#Choose_a_Customer-link{0}"").click(function (event) {{ $(""#Choose_a_Customer{0}"").dialog(""open""); event.preventDefault(); }});
}});
", ID),
            true);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

file **WebForm1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUserControl1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">       
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl1" LinkText="Instance1" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <p>Content of dialog 1</p>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </uc1:WebUserControl1>

                <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl2" LinkText="Instance2" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <p>Content of dialog 2</p>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </uc1:WebUserControl1>

                <uc1:WebUserControl1 runat="server" ID="WebUserControl3" LinkText="Instance3" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <p>Content of dialog 3</p>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </uc1:WebUserControl1>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, that solved the initial problem!  However, now after the postback, the dialog box won't open at all.  I guess technically, this isn't a new problem, as it wouldn't before your suggested fix either.  A step in the right direction!  Any advice on how to get the script to still work after postback?  Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Boris.  I read the article, but I'm not sure how to apply it in this case.  $(document).ready() vs pageLoad()... I don't understand how this is applicable.  I'm willing to learn if you are willing to explain!

Comment: I changed my ansver, please try

Comment: I tried:
    $(function pageLoad() {...
and:
    $(document).ready(function () {....
neither worked. Same result.

Comment: perhaps I should add.... there is already a ScriptManager as all of this is inside an update panel.

Comment: Ok!  I'm going to try this out.  Thank you!

Comment: It does work!  Thank you!  Now I'm going to try and integrate this into my environment which is dynamically populated.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Ok, I know what the problem is, and I think I know how to solve it, but I might need a little help with the javascript syntax.

The issue is that I have multiple instances of the dialog box on the same page.  If I duplicate the script, only the last one works.  I need to have a single instance of the script that will work for multiple dialog boxes. I'll play around and see if I can get it to work.  Thank you again!

Comment: Ug.  I don't know how to do this.  I am adding these dialog boxes to the page dynamically and they are in a user control.  I'm going to have to put some thought into generating the javascript dynamically as well, I guess.  This is getting messier than I would have liked.

I tried to upvote you but it said I don't have enough points.